# Center Selected Item in Listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

hello I want to center Currently selected item of listview. ie scroll item to center of listview even if the listview has one item when it is clicked it should move to center of listview.

IE when i click on item inside on itemclick listner it should center the currently selected item. 
My sample code is

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    if (civ != null) {

        // civ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        civ.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    civ = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.civ_shelfBook_BookImage);

    BooksAdapter.selectedPosition = position;
    ref.get(civ.getShelfID()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    DetailActivity.shelfID = civ.getShelfID();
    DetailActivity.currentlySelected = position;

    // GeneralModel.actionIntent = new Intent(contex, DetailActivity.class);
    // activity.startActivity(GeneralModel.actionIntent);
    // GeneralModel.actionIntent = null;

    Toast.makeText(contex, "Child Clicked" + civ.shelfID,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //

}
```

Comment: You want to center it in the *entire* `ListView` or in it's row? Do you have an image of what you want?

Comment: I want to Center the Selected Row. ie if my listview has 10 rows and i click on 2nd row it should be on the position where 5th row was.  no matter if i would have to give padding to it. it would be good as far as it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can do something like this.. see my example .

This example has a textview items . When an item is clicked the text will be centered. You can modify as per your requirement to have a custom view instead of textview

```
    ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    stringArrayList.add("ONE");
    stringArrayList.add("TWO");
    stringArrayList.add("THREE");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    setContentView(listView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        TextView previousView = null; // to hold the previous clicked view
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            if(previousView != null) {
                // revert the previous view when a new item is clicked
                previousView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            }
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            previousView = textView;
        }
    });
```